# Working with detached objects and composite relation tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a User entity, it as a list of Roles. The list of roles comes from a UserRole table that uses composite keys UserId and RoleId

From the admin client a User is updated which means its detached.
My code looks like

```
public void UpdateUser(User user)
{
    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password))
        db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Password).IsModified = false;
    else
    {
        HashPassword(user);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

How can I make EF aware of the changes made to the relation table?

**edit:**
With relations that has its own primary key you can iterate over the collection and do `db.Entry(role).State = role.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;`

This does not work with composite key relations like my Role > User relation. How can I fix that?

**edit2:**
Tried this, did not work

```
var roles = user.Roles.Select(r => db.Roles.Find(r.Id)).ToList();
user.Roles.Clear();
roles.ForEach(user.Roles.Add);
```

Comment: I assume that `user` also contains its `Roles` after editing?

Comment: The incoming detached User have the correct roles from client, but it does not get updated by db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: No, that only affects scalar properties. You have to sync the Roles yourself.

Comment: I would just replace the `Roles` in `user`. This deletes the old junction records and creates new ones.